# model.predict(sample) returning TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-3.7

I keep running into this error when I try to predict based on fitted model.

```
training, testing = train_test_split(gesture, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
x = training.drop('CLASS', axis = 1)                    # remove the Class column from Training dataframe
y = testing.drop('CLASS', axis = 1)                     # remove the Class column from Testing dataframe
f_train = x.values.tolist()
l_train = training['CLASS'].values.tolist()             # make a list of class identifiers from Training dataframe
f_test = y.values.tolist()

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(f_train, l_train)
predictions = knn.predict(f_test)
```

The error occurs in the last line of the above code and the error message is given below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Umair Khan\Dropbox\`Shift betweeen PCs\Work\EMG Hand Gesture\Codes\ML_on_CSV.py", line 39, in <module>
    predictions = knn.predict(f_test)
  File "C:\Users\Umair Khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_regression.py", line 185, in predict
    y_pred = np.mean(_y[neigh_ind], axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in mean
  File "C:\Users\Umair Khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3335, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umair Khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 151, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

`f_test` is a list of lists like such `[[16, 30, 35, 250, -1, 0.5, 35, 0.03, 0.02], [16, 30, 35, 250, -1, 0.5, 35, 0.03, 0.02]]`

I have also tried passing an array in `predict(sample)` but the issue still remains.

```
predictions = knn.predict(np.array(f_test).astype(np.float))
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more of the error traceback.  And info on the function inputs, particularly shape and dtype.

I've seen this error message when working with `structured arrays`.  But it's not obvious where those might arise in your code.

```
In [15]: np.ones((2,), dtype='i,i')                                             
Out[15]: array([(1, 1), (1, 1)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [16]: np.sum(np.ones((2,), dtype='i,i'))                                     
....
---> 87     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     88 
     89 

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Comment: `f_train` and `f_test` are lists of lists representing 9 features across 1200 samples and 300 samples respectively. And `l_train` is a list of 1200 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
changed dtype of `l_train` from *string* to *float* and the error disappeared. `f_train` and `f_test` were already of type float.